# Google Cloud SQL import and connection via mysql client not working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have just set up a Google Cloud SQL instance, but am unable to import to it using a SQL dump file and also cannot connect to it from the command line or MySQL Workbench.

When trying to import, I get the error "An unknown error occurred" with no further details.  I have confirmed that the 'USE [db name]' statement is in the file, which seems to be everyone else's solution.  All tables are MyISAM with no binary data.

When trying to connect via MySQL Workbench or the command line, I am able to connect to the server, but entering a 'USE [db name]' results in an 'Unknown database [db name]' error.  I have also tried including the app name ('USE [app engine name]:[db name]'), which throws a sql syntax error due to the hyphens in the app engine instance name.  I am certain that the db name I am using exists and is set up for external connections.

At this point I have a Cloud SQL instance up and running, but am completely unable to get data to it either by importing or by connecting to it with a SQL client.  What can I do to move forward?

Answer (score 0):

After some more noodling around, I ran 'show databases' and got the results: information_schema, mysql, and performance_schema.  That mysql schema looked a little odd so I selected it ('USE mysql') and then ran 'SHOW tables', which resulted in a list of tables that included a table matching the name of my database (let's assume that the database name is 'db') according to Google Cloud SQL.  So it appears that setting up a Google Cloud SQL instance creates a schema named 'mysql' and then creates a table in that schema that matches the Google Cloud SQL instance name, which is not terribly useful to me.  I was able to change my SQL import file's line 'USE db' to 'USE mysql' and was then able to import my data without problems.  Weird, but at least things are working now.